# Broadcast stream works fine without asBroadcastStream() method

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I want to know why my stream don't throw any error even if I don't use the `asBroadcastStream()` method ?

Generally if we want to listen the `stream` twice we need to put `asBroadcastStream()` method. but it works fine without the method.

```
class PlayScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      PlayScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<PlayScreen> createState() => _PlayScreenState();
    }
    
    class _PlayScreenState extends State<PlayScreen> {
      Stream<int> generateStream(int max) async* {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
          yield i;
        }
      }
    
      Stream get numberStream => generateStream(1000);
    
      int currentNumber = -1;
    
      int anotherNumber = -1;
    
      void init() {
        numberStream.listen((event) {
          setState(() {
            currentNumber = event;
          });
        });
    
        numberStream.listen((event) {
          setState(() {
            anotherNumber = event;
          });
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        init();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.add))],
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(currentNumber.toString()),
                Text(anotherNumber.toString()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image: Works fine without the Error]

Comment: You are not listening to the same stream twice. Every time you call the `numberStream` getter it is instantiating a new stream with `generateStream(1000)`. The listen events are on two different instances of the stream.

Comment: Okay I get it thanks @mmcdon20